# Countifs with a range and a value with formula in vba

Tags: vba, formula

I can't get this vba coding to work, please help:

```
Range("C1").Formula ="=Countifs(B2:B10,>&A1)"
```

I want to count cells with value greater than A1 in range B2:B10.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Range("C1").Formula = "=COUNTIF(B2:B10,"">"" & A1)"
```